# validate textarea in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I want to validate textarea as not empty!but this code is not working and this is not showing me an validate error message from model! my code is as below,

```
public $validate = array(
    'address' => array(
        'rule' => array('validateAddress'),
        'message'  => 'Address is required',
    ),
);    

public function validateAddress() {
    if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]['address'])) {
        debug('hi');
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

please help me for textarea validation in cakephp! Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom validation rule always returns `true`. It should return `false` when the validation fails:

```
public function validateAddress() {
    if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]['address'])) {
        //debug('hi');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

That said, for such a simple rule, you should use the core validation rule `notempty`:

```
public $validate = array(
    'address' => array(
        'rule'    => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Address is required'
    )
);
```

Comment: You're answer is correct but you're all missing the `$check` parameter. Every validation function gets an `$check` param as it's first parameter. This param is an array with the only key being the field being checked so in your case: `$check['address']`. So you don't need to use `$this->data` to check the field that the custom validation method is meant for - it is still correct but there is no point. You should use the `$data` Class property if the validation requires that the field being checked is validated against another field.

Answer (score 1):

You are always returning `true`. So it will always validate. Try following:

```
public function validateAddress() {
    if(empty($this->data[$this->alias]['address'])) {
        debug('hi');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```